# How to debug gwt application at eclipse che

Tags: gwt, eclipse-che

Is there a best approach to debug maven GWT application at Eclipse Che?
Whenever I run gwt:run-codeserver it maps to a random external port on docker in order to serve multiple users, and the client is expecting to use the port, specified at pom configuration.